# Why does my Atheros AR9285 connect at only 65 Mbits/sec?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, atheros

I have an ASUS K53E laptop, running Ubuntu 12.04. Love it, the only OS so far which doesn't give me problems!

Anyway, my wireless network adapter is pretty much crap. It runs at only 65 Mbit/s, while it can handle 300 Mbit/s. It's an Atheros AR9285.

I googled around, found suggestions of setting the channel and frequency of my router. So set the 5 GHz band to force 40 MHz and Wireless-N, and I set the 2.4 GHz band to choose between 20 and 40 MHz, also forcing Wireless-N. My router is a Cisco Linksys E3200.

When I run a speedtest at speedtest.net, I get 21 MB/s download and an unstable 9 MB/s upload. When downloading an Ubuntu ISO from a local site I get about 2 MB/s download speed, can be a lot better methinks.

Is there another way that I can tune up the speed of this card a bit? Or should I get a replacement (I was looking at the Intel 6235), and if I do so, will Ubuntu recognize it immediately after install or do I have to install some more stuff?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Anyway, my wireless network adapter is pretty much crap.*

Amen!

> *Or should I get a replacement (I was looking at the Intel 6235)*

To be honest, this is the easiest and most-troublefree option. The Intel 6235 will work out of the box, no extra drivers needed -- ever! (Intel's Wifi drivers are all open-source and come with the Linux kernel).

I have an Intel 6230 (older version of 6235 with Bluetooth 3.0) and an Intel 6300; both work flawlessly with Ubuntu 12.04 and connect at 300 Mb/s at close-ish distances; as you go further they will gracefully go down in 30 Mbps steps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I missed the lack of Bluetooth on this laptop, so I will definitely get the Intel 6235 at some point. Thanks for confirming, though which do you think is better, the 623(0/5) or the 6300, or does it make almost no difference? I'd like to get the best out of my wireless internet connection :)

Comment: @RickKerkhof: The 6300 *does not* have Bluetooth; it supports 3 antennas for a total of up to 450 Mbps, but (a) your router only goes up to 300 and (b) Asus probably included only two antennas/connectors anyway. Short answer: 6235 or 6230 all the way! If I answered your question, please remember to accept the answer (tick/check mark on left) so the question can be "closed".

Comment: Okay, thanks, ASUS indeed only included 2 antenna's in this thing. I will definitely try to get my hands on an Intel 6235 then :) Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Okay, I got the Intel 6235 in today, and it works like a charm! It connects at 180 Mbit/s max, and a speedtest on that speed gives me 80 Mbit/s, double of what I had with the Atheros :) Installing the Intel was as simple as plug the antenna's over and boot the laptop!

Answer (score 0):

With AR9285 (Ubuntu Lucid, custom kernel version 3.3.0-rc1), I managed to get 150Mbps link speed (as shown by `iwconfig`).

Access point is TEW-638APB. At first, it connected at 65 Mbps, but after setting **auto 20/40 MHz** channel width and **strong uppercase/lowercase password** in the access point settings, it works. Speedtest.net gives 40 Mbit per second download rate (wired card gives 98 with the same server).

UPD: Checked with stock kernel 2.6.32-44-generic, and I got even better results: 7 MiB/s (with TEW-638APB) or 9 MiB/s (with TL-WR842ND) download
UPD2: Security was set to WPA2-PSK+AES in all cases

Comment: Could you please give further description on where and how to apply your recommended settings? Thank you! :-)