# Unable to connect to open wireless network

Tags: 12.04, wireless, atheros

I am unable to connect to a wifi network.
When I try to connect I can see that either the network stops broadcast or my adapter doesn't recieve it.
Thank you.

Comment: What **Ubuntu** version? (12.04, 13.04) What brand/model of WiFi modem are you using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04 and my wifi adapter manufacturer is atheros.I am unable to connect to only one particular network.

Comment: The same **Atheros AR9285** as your other question?

Comment: Yes. I am unable to connect to an open network sometimes.

Comment: This may relate to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/172774/wireless-unstable-with-an-atheros-ar9285 (unresolved) OR http://askubuntu.com/questions/164118/why-does-my-atheros-ar9285-connect-at-only-65-mbits-sec

Comment: Okay I'll check them and tell you later.Thank you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9334/discussion-between-m-tarun-and-david6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your drivers and your routers firmware.  The problem migght be with the router. Try replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried loading the **backports** resources?

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-lucid-generic
```

Then, reboot.

---

You are probably better off just buying a cheap USB modem, as the Atheros AR9285 in known to have these type of issues.

Comment: I am using compat-drivers.